# Sending file to a user's browser in php

Tags: php

I'm not really good at php, so please forgive me, if this question seems stupid for you. :)

I've made a simple script which improves a text subtitle file (.srt) and sends it back to user (as newfile.srt). And it works fine. But there is one thing I can't understand. After sending the file to user's browser:

```
$tmpName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'newfile');
$file = fopen($tmpName, 'w') or die("Can't open file!");
$output = implode("\r\n", $com); // $com is an array with lines of the new file
fwrite($file, $output);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/srt');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=newfile.srt');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpName));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($tmpName);
unlink($tmpName);
```

I would like to redirect the user to another page. Like that:

```
header('Location: http://myserver.com/newpage.php');
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Even if I try to echo after the lines written above it doesn't seem to work - nothing happens. Can you tell me why? And what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send two sets of headers in the same response.

What you can do in your case is to use some JavaScript to handle two requests:

1. Open the download script in a new tab. This tab will immediately close itself as soon as the download begins
2. Redirect the current page to newpage.php

You can likely handle the new tab by simply setting target="_blank" on your form, if that's how your script currently works. Then bind a function to the onsubmit event to redirect the current page afterwards.

Either way, you're not going to be able to do this with just PHP